# Opening file in binary mode and saving it adds new line

Tags: ruby, file-io, binary, newline

Why does this add a new line to every line in the file?

```
text = File.read('1.txt', mode: 'rb', encoding: 'UTF-8')  
File.write('1.txt', text, encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

If I remove binary mode, it is normal again, but I need it for another encoding (UTF-16LE).

Test it - http://asdfasd.net/ruby/binary_adds_newline.zip

Comment: the simple answer is adding `mode: 'wb'`, or Windows will add \r

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ran some tests; it depends on the way your lines end. When they end with *either* `LF` (`\n`) or `CR` (`\r`) it will produce output like you expect. That is, no new lines are added. However, if you have `CRLF` (`\r\n`) it will add a `CR` character after each line, thus ending it effectively with `CRCR+LF` which produces the extra line.

Most programming editors allow you to select an option which makes the line endings visible.

I am not exactly sure why this happens, but likely has to do with the following snippet from [the IO docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode) at the `'b'` mode:

> Suppresses EOL <-> CRLF conversion on Windows.

It appears that when *not* using binary mode, CRLF (default end-of-lines on Windows) are converted to LF's. The simple solution thus seems to just replace all `\r\n` by either `\n` or `\r`. You can do that like this:

```
File.open('converted.txt', 'wb') do |converted|
  File.open('1.txt', 'rb').each_line do |line|
    converted << line.gsub("\r\n", "\n") # Replace CRLF with LF
  end
end
```

If you run the script multiple times on the same file, you should make sure to replace CRLF with LF before you write it back:

```
# Note the .gsub at the end here
text = File.read('1.txt', mode: 'rb', encoding: 'UTF-8').gsub("\r\n", "\n")
File.write('1.txt', text, encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Crazy stuff. I do always use `LF (\n)` only, but it still adds new line. For example, we can use your `converted.txt` with the same result. First time you run it, it adds \r without visible changes, only file size get bigger, next time you run it, it starts add lines. At least now I know I am not crazy :) I will just `gsub('\r\n', '\n')` before saving.

Comment: @Qiao You need to use double quotes, `"\r\n"` and `"\n"` otherwise it will not work, something with escaping inside single quotes. You can prevent the extra lines by doing your `text=` like this: `text = File.read('converted.txt', mode: 'rb', encoding: 'UTF-8').gsub("\r\n", "\n")`. Then you can read/write as many times as you want, just know the resulting file will then have CRLF because that is apparently done automatically by Ruby; it transforms newlines to CRLF on Windows when you write without binary mode.

Comment: @Qiao Well, be careful that you do not have files that use CR (= `"\r"`) as end-of-line then :) Otherwise you are removing those entirely.

Comment: Yep, just tested it. Btw, `gsub("\r", "")` seems to be the best

Comment: it stil adds something to the file. File original size is 85 bite, when you run script first time it become 89. With `gsub("\r", "")` or `gsub("\r\n", "\n")`. So there should be something else, but not visible.

Comment: @Qiao Let me check. 1.txt with 3 lines, 2x CRLF is indeed 85 bytes. Hmm, I cannot reproduce. When running the script multiple times it remains 85 bytes. I used the code I put in the edit of my answer. That will keep 1.txt at 85 bytes.

Comment: @Qiao `converted.txt` has line endings LF, while `1.txt` has line endings CRLF. You can see the line endings with (for example) [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html), under View > End of Line.

Comment: What is the difference between http://asdfasd.net/ruby/1/1.txt (89) and http://asdfasd.net/ruby/1/converted.txt (95)? First was got from second with `text = File.read('1.txt', mode: 'rb', encoding: 'UTF-8').gsub("\r\n", "\n"); File.write('1.txt', text, encoding: 'UTF-8')`

Comment: `mode: 'wb'` fixed this problem. http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/435671-bug-file-write-n-produces-carriage-return-line-feed